# Why std::unique_ptr is not compatible with assignement operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

For example:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<int> int_ptr = new int(10); // error: conversion from ‘int*’ to non-scalar type ‘std::unique_ptr’ requested

std::unique_ptr<int> pointer(new int(10));  // this work fine
```

Comment: @armagedescu for shared_ptr also generate same error.

Comment: @armagedescu `unique_ptr` is not a singleton.  You can have N separate instances with N unique values.  That is the opposite of what a singleton allows.

Comment: @armagedescu Singleton means globally unique and doesn't apply to `unique_ptr`. You're thinking of "unique ownership" which applies to `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @armagedescu -- the question in that link does say, in passing, that `unique_ptr` is a singleton, but that's not the point of the question, and none of the comments or answers addressed that assertion. Weak authority at best. Idiomatically, "singleton" means a globally shared single object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are initialization, but not assignment. The 1st one is copy initialization, the 2nd one is direct initialization. The [constructor of `std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) taking raw pointer is marked as `explicit`, it could be used in [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) but not [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

> ```
> explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;
> ```

> Direct-initialization is more permissive than copy-initialization: copy-initialization only considers non-explicit constructors and non-explicit user-defined conversion functions, while direct-initialization considers all constructors and all user-defined conversion functions.